# Resurfacing bug: "could not parse proxy url" error message

Tags: bug, api, authentication, api-v2.2

According to [this question](https://stackapps.com/questions/3631/bug-in-the-stackexchange-api-getting-could-not-parse-proxy-url-when-user-not), the "could not parse proxy url" bug was solved more than 2 years ago.

However, when using the client-side OAuth flow, the aforementioned error message appears when executing `SE.authenticate`. Moreover, neither of `success` and `error` functions within `SE.authenticate` are executed. Instead, the user will be redirected to a page that tells him:

```
Application Login Failure

An error occurred while login into an application.
Error Details

error description: could not parse proxy url
```

although the login **is** successful, as the username appears in the page top navbar.

I encountered this error while developing a Firefox add-on that uses Stack Exchange API. You can confirm the bug by visiting [this SE documentation page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib) and clicking on the **demo "Run Example" button** at the bottom of the page.

**Important Notice**

The bug takes place only when the user is not already logged in. Otherwise, he won't see this error.

Comment: I tried with both Firefox and Chrome, usual profile and new profile, and all cases have given the same error so far. And I just tried using a remote server (with different OS and internet connection), only to face the same error again. I am beginning to think it has something to do with my user, or rather my choice of OpenID authentication (I use Google OpenID).

Comment: Tried with SE auth, and it is the same. Made a new dummy account to test with it and got the same error again. I should mention that pressing the "Run Example" for a second time will authenitcate successfully and give the alert box, in all cases. Any ideas?

Comment: You might make it clear that this bug only occurs on a cold login.  When I completely de-auth a machine and then try the test page, I see the failure as you describe (after being asked to sign in and successfully doing so).  Once I am signed in to SE, *then* the second attempt at auth succeeds. I can see that this would be quite annoying.

Comment: You're right. I have updated the question now.

Comment: I just ran into this issue myself. I was also running into a secondary issue. I think I figured out what was causing the second issue but I'm not sure if it's a bug in the SE.authenticate() flow (using the SDK), or working as intended. Basically, if I didn't re-run SE.init() every time I tried to use SE.authenticate() within a single session, the proxy URL would return "undefined" at the end. Now that I figured out how to get around that, I still run into the issue mentioned here.

Comment: Also ran into this error.

Comment: @Linostar I'm also facing this issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @yusaku Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Oh.. Thanks. I will implement it without the library.

Comment: is there any fix for this ?