# Does a user only need to log in once to access all sites?

Tags: support, authentication

When I use stack exchange sites on my desktop web browser, I log in once using stack exchange ID and then when I navigate to sites I don't belong to, it automatically associates me with the new site.  Does it work the same when using the StackExchange API?  Or do we have to do something special in order to register with a new site?

Comment: [Try it and see.](http://stackapps.com/q/6166/7653)