# Stackoverflow Javascript Authentication error

Tags: support, api, javascript, api-v2.2, authentication

Using the Stack Overflow javascript authentication API, I get this error:

> Application Login Failure An error occurred while login into an
>   application.
>
> Error Details
>   error description: could not parse proxy url

I checked regarding this issue and I found a few URLs:

- [Bug in the StackExchange Api ? getting "could not parse proxy url" when user not logged in](https://stackapps.com/questions/3631/bug-in-the-stackexchange-api-getting-could-not-parse-proxy-url-when-user-not)
- [Resurfacing bug: "could not parse proxy url" error message](https://stackapps.com/questions/6166/resurfacing-bug-could-not-parse-proxy-url-error-message)

Still I could not solve this.

Is there any other way apart from javascript Authentication to get an user's Stack Overflow reputation?

Please do help me on this.

Comment: This is a bug.  Go upvote the bug report you linked and maybe it'll be a small step closer to getting fixed. ;)

Comment: May be fixed now. See http://stackapps.com/questions/6938/implicit-flow-isnt-redirecting